# How to run a server-client based cpp files from php on webpage

Tags: php, c++, sockets, web-development-server

I have a server-client based socket program written in c++. I have build a wrapper php file to run it and it runs very well on terminal.

`<?php exec("code/./server", $output);
 exec("clients/./O 10.193.2.163", $output);
 exec("clients/./X 10.193.2.163", $output) ; ?>`

Above is the simple php wrapper for running server first and then running both the clients executables giving the IP (the IP is currently the localhost).

But when I run the same from a webpage, the page keep on loading and does not proceeds. What am I missing here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the permissions...

Comment: @alu : I have checked the permissions. They are fine

Answer (score 0):

Am I right you are trying to start the c++ client and the coresponding server in the same php file? Try to start the c++-based client first, then fire the client program.

But I think what you really trying to do is to connect from the php side to the server. PHP does have a socket api, so you probably don't need to start via exec a client.

Comment: Yes I am starting the c++ server and 2 c++ clients in the same php file via exec. The code structure is something that I can't use php socket apis here. I checked it now and the php code does not return from the exec command for the server i.e. exec("code/./server &", $output); . So, my clients are never fired. (I put an & thinking it will run in background, but no help. ) Any insights now ?

Comment: When you try to start the c++ part from the php file - you've gonna have a bad time. If the php file executed during serving a web page, it'll be stopped after 60seconds or so.

start the server written in c++ in a terminal or as service and remove exec("code/./server", $output); from the php file.